# Gradle command line

Tags: bash, shell, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to run a shell script with gradle. I currently have something like this

```
def test = project.tasks.create("test", Exec) {
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'bash C:/my file dir/script.sh'
}
```

The problem is that I cannot run this script because i have spaces in my dir name. I have tried everything e.g:

```
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'bash C:/my file dir/script.sh'.tokenize() 
commandLine 'bash', '-c', ['bash', 'C:/my file dir/script.sh']
commandLine 'bash', '-c', new StringBuilder().append('bash').append('C:/my file dir/script.sh')
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'bash "C:/my file dir/script.sh"'
File dir = file('C:/my file dir/script.sh')
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'bash ' + dir.getAbsolutePath();
```

Im using windows7 64bit and if I use a path without spaces the script runs perfectly, therefore the only issue as I can see is how gradle handles spaces.

Comment: Try `commandLine 'bash', 'C:/my file dir/script.sh'`

Comment: It doesn't work. I also tried -> commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'bash C:/my\\ file\\ dir/script.sh' and it doesn't work

Comment: Are you using cygwin or linux/unix? The answer depends on it. I'm confused that 'bash' is used together with win paths. One option is to try unix paths, another is to use 'cmd', '/c' instead of 'bash', '-c'

Comment: I was using cygwin on windows.

Comment: In cygwin you may try using unix-like paths in double quotes, for example: bash -c "/c/Users/username/Documents/test\ dir/test.sh"

Comment: Ok, will try it, thanks!